# Angular2 webpack app misses assets after build

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have an issue with an Angular2 app where I have modified the UI. When I test the app using `ng serve` everything works just fine. But if I build the app, it stops working.

The issue is, that I have a record button with a microphone photo on it. When the button is clicked, I just get a (border) indicator of the recording time left.

When I build the project, the picture for the icon is missing, and the border animation works up to halfway, after witch it just resets back to the original state.

I can get the icon to be shown if I manually copy the picture to the `dist` folder, but the animation is not working past the half way. I would like to know why this is happening in the first place (why it is working using `ng serve` but not after building).

Here is the "build log"

```
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.22
Time: 23181ms
                                   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    ffe81decef5f1cb7babcc1d151d30253.jpg  65.3 kB          [emitted]
     ...js   861 kB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
   styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js  11.7 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
                               inline.js  1.39 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js.gz  3.08 kB          [emitted]
  ...js.gz   194 kB          [emitted]
                              index.html  1.87 kB          [emitted]
                       assets/.npmignore  0 bytes          [emitted]
chunk    {0} ...js (main) 2.07 MB {1} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js (styles) 17.7 kB {2} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} inline.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in ...js from UglifyJs
 unused fnc scheduleMicroTask [...js:226,9]
 unused fnc getTypeNameForDebugging [...js:233,9]
 unused fnc isBoolean [...js:253,9]
 unused fnc isNumber [...js:256,9]
 unused fnc isfnc [...js:262,9]
 unused fnc isType [...js:265,9]
 unused fnc isPromise [...js:275,9]
 unused fnc isDate [...js:283,9]
 unused fnc noop [...js:286,9]
 unused fnc serializeEnum [...js:306,9]
 unused fnc deserializeEnum [...js:309,9]
 unused fnc resolveEnumToken [...js:312,9]
 unused fnc looseIdentical [...js:442,9]
 unused fnc getMapKey [...js:447,9]
 unused fnc print [...js:459,9]
 unused fnc warn [...js:462,9]
 unused fnc setValueOnPath [...js:495,9]
 unused fnc hasConstructor [...js:545,9]
 unused fnc escape [...js:548,9]
Side effects in init of unused var Math [...js:239,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RegExp [...js:433,4]
Side effects in init of unused var fncWrapper [...js:434,4]
Side effects in init of unused var Json [...js:466,4]
Side effects in init of unused var DateWrapper [...js:476,4]
 unused fnc isBoolean [...js:652,9]
 unused fnc isNumber [...js:655,9]
 unused fnc isType [...js:664,9]
 unused fnc isStringMap [...js:667,9]
 unused fnc isStrictStringMap [...js:671,9]
 unused fnc isDate [...js:682,9]
 unused fnc noop [...js:685,9]
 unused fnc serializeEnum [...js:705,9]
 unused fnc deserializeEnum [...js:708,9]
 unused fnc resolveEnumToken [...js:711,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBlank [...js:849,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBool [...js:852,9]
 unused fnc setValueOnPath [...js:894,9]
 unused fnc evalExpression [...js:931,9]
 unused fnc hasConstructor [...js:944,9]
 unused fnc escape [...js:947,9]
 unused fnc escapeRegExp [...js:950,9]
Side effects in init of unused var STRING_MAP_PROTO [...js:670,4]
Side effects in init of unused var StringJoiner [...js:782,4]
Side effects in init of unused var NumberWrapper [...js:791,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RegExp [...js:832,4]
Side effects in init of unused var fncWrapper [...js:833,4]
Side effects in init of unused var Json [...js:865,4]
Side effects in init of unused var DateWrapper [...js:875,4]
 unused fnc isListLikeIterable [...js:1290,9]
 unused fnc areIterablesEqual [...js:1297,9]
 unused fnc iterateListLike [...js:1311,9]
Side effects in init of unused var INT_TYPE [...js:1516,4]
Side effects in init of unused var CATCH_ERROR_VAR [...js:1902,4]
Side effects in init of unused var CATCH_STACK_VAR [...js:1903,4]
Side effects in init of unused var CommentStmt [...js:2051,4]
 unused fnc setDOM [...js:2801,9]
Side effects in init of unused var RenderDebugInfo [...js:3225,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AnimationPlayer [...js:3244,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ViewMetadata [...js:3259,4]
 unused fnc scheduleMicroTask [...js:3352,9]
 unused fnc isBoolean [...js:3379,9]
 unused fnc isType [...js:3391,9]
 unused fnc isStrictStringMap [...js:3398,9]
 unused fnc noop [...js:3412,9]
 unused fnc serializeEnum [...js:3432,9]
 unused fnc deserializeEnum [...js:3435,9]
 unused fnc resolveEnumToken [...js:3438,9]
 unused fnc looseIdentical [...js:3568,9]
 unused fnc getMapKey [...js:3573,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBlank [...js:3576,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBool [...js:3579,9]
 unused fnc print [...js:3585,9]
 unused fnc warn [...js:3588,9]
 unused fnc setValueOnPath [...js:3621,9]
 unused fnc evalExpression [...js:3658,9]
 unused fnc isPrimitive [...js:3668,9]
 unused fnc hasConstructor [...js:3671,9]
 unused fnc escape [...js:3674,9]
 unused fnc escapeRegExp [...js:3677,9]
Side effects in init of unused var Math [...js:3365,4]
Side effects in init of unused var STRING_MAP_PROTO [...js:3397,4]
Side effects in init of unused var StringJoiner [...js:3509,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RegExp [...js:3559,4]
Side effects in init of unused var fncWrapper [...js:3560,4]
Side effects in init of unused var UNDEFINED [...js:3747,4]
Side effects in init of unused var CompileMetadataWithIdentifier [...js:3748,4]
 unused fnc scheduleMicroTask [...js:4378,9]
 unused fnc getTypeNameForDebugging [...js:4385,9]
 unused fnc isBoolean [...js:4405,9]
 unused fnc isNumber [...js:4408,9]
 unused fnc isType [...js:4417,9]
 unused fnc isStrictStringMap [...js:4424,9]
 unused fnc isDate [...js:4435,9]
 unused fnc noop [...js:4438,9]
 unused fnc stringify [...js:4439,9]
 unused fnc serializeEnum [...js:4458,9]
 unused fnc deserializeEnum [...js:4461,9]
 unused fnc resolveEnumToken [...js:4464,9]
 unused fnc getMapKey [...js:4599,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBlank [...js:4602,9]
 unused fnc print [...js:4611,9]
 unused fnc warn [...js:4614,9]
 unused fnc setValueOnPath [...js:4647,9]
 unused fnc evalExpression [...js:4684,9]
 unused fnc escape [...js:4700,9]
 unused fnc escapeRegExp [...js:4703,9]
Side effects in init of unused var Math [...js:4391,4]
Side effects in init of unused var STRING_MAP_PROTO [...js:4423,4]
Side effects in init of unused var StringJoiner [...js:4535,4]
Side effects in init of unused var NumberWrapper [...js:4544,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RegExp [...js:4585,4]
Side effects in init of unused var fncWrapper [...js:4586,4]
Side effects in init of unused var Json [...js:4618,4]
Side effects in init of unused var DateWrapper [...js:4628,4]
 unused fnc scheduleMicroTask [...js:4777,9]
 unused fnc getTypeNameForDebugging [...js:4784,9]
 unused fnc isBoolean [...js:4804,9]
 unused fnc isType [...js:4816,9]
 unused fnc isStringMap [...js:4819,9]
 unused fnc isStrictStringMap [...js:4823,9]
 unused fnc isPromise [...js:4826,9]
 unused fnc isDate [...js:4834,9]
 unused fnc noop [...js:4837,9]
 unused fnc serializeEnum [...js:4857,9]
 unused fnc deserializeEnum [...js:4860,9]
 unused fnc resolveEnumToken [...js:4863,9]
 unused fnc looseIdentical [...js:4993,9]
 unused fnc getMapKey [...js:4998,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBlank [...js:5001,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBool [...js:5004,9]
 unused fnc print [...js:5010,9]
 unused fnc warn [...js:5013,9]
 unused fnc evalExpression [...js:5083,9]
 unused fnc isPrimitive [...js:5093,9]
 unused fnc hasConstructor [...js:5096,9]
 unused fnc escape [...js:5099,9]
 unused fnc escapeRegExp [...js:5102,9]
Side effects in init of unused var Math [...js:4790,4]
Side effects in init of unused var STRING_MAP_PROTO [...js:4822,4]
Side effects in init of unused var StringJoiner [...js:4934,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RegExp [...js:4984,4]
Side effects in init of unused var fncWrapper [...js:4985,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__di_reflective_provider__ [...js:5273,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__di_reflective_key__ [...js:5274,25]
 unused fnc isListLikeIterable [...js:5679,9]
 unused fnc areIterablesEqual [...js:5686,9]
 unused fnc iterateListLike [...js:5700,9]
Side effects in init of unused var SetWrapper [...js:5733,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_operator_toPromise___default [...js:5750,25]
 unreachable code [...js:6504,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:6504,4]
 unused fnc isListLikeIterable [...js:7255,9]
 unused fnc areIterablesEqual [...js:7262,9]
 unused fnc iterateListLike [...js:7276,9]
Side effects in init of unused var MapWrapper [...js:7038,4]
Side effects in init of unused var SetWrapper [...js:7309,4]
 unreachable code [...js:7655,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:7655,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ChangeDetectionStrategyEnum [...js:8458,4]
 unreachable code [...js:8802,8]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:8802,8]
 unreachable code [...js:8831,8]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:8831,8]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_rxjs_Subject___default [...js:8848,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable___default [...js:8850,25]
Side effects in init of unused var RenderTypes [...js:9187,4]
 unused fnc createUrlResolverWithoutPackagePrefix [...js:9285,9]
 unused fnc createOfflineCompileUrlResolver [...js:9288,9]
 unused fnc areIterablesEqual [...js:10919,9]
 unused fnc iterateListLike [...js:10933,9]
Side effects in init of unused var MapWrapper [...js:10695,4]
Side effects in init of unused var SetWrapper [...js:10966,4]
Side effects in init of unused var CHANGE_DETECTOR_STATUS_VALUES [...js:14070,4]
Side effects in init of unused var wtfStartTimeRange [...js:14749,4]
Side effects in init of unused var wtfEndTimeRange [...js:14756,4]
Side effects in init of unused var HTMLCollection [...js:15389,4]
 unused var SELECT_DIRECTIVES [...js:15557,4]
 unused fnc isControl [...js:15615,9]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_rxjs_observable_fromPromise___default [...js:15566,25]
 unused var $PIPE [...js:17787,4]
 unused var $TILDA [...js:17788,4]
 unused var $AT [...js:17789,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AstTransformer [...js:18698,4]
 unreachable code [...js:18861,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:18861,4]
 unreachable code [...js:19313,8]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:19313,8]
Non-strict equality against boolean: != true [...js:19770,15]
Side effects in init of unused var OutputEmitter [...js:20152,4]
 unused fnc destroyPlatform [...js:21485,9]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_rxjs_Subject___default [...js:23071,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_rxjs_Observable___default [...js:23073,25]
Non-strict equality against boolean: != false [...js:24371,50]
Side effects in init of unused var ELEMENT_PROBE_PROVIDERS_PROD_MODE [...js:25151,4]
 unused var SAFE_SRCSET_PATTERN [...js:25695,4]
 unreachable code [...js:25878,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:25878,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__common_app_data_proxy___default [...js:25721,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__common_audio_proxy___default [...js:25723,25]
 unreachable code [...js:25983,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:25983,4]
 unreachable code [...js:26077,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:26077,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__src_localization__ [...js:26759,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__src_directives_index__ [...js:26761,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__src_pipes_index__ [...js:26762,25]
Side effects in init of unused var matches [...js:27290,12]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__message_bundle__ [...js:28627,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__serializers_xliff__ [...js:28628,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__serializers_xmb__ [...js:28629,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__serializers_xtb__ [...js:28630,25]
Side effects in init of unused var strCases [...js:29330,12]
 unused fnc group [...js:33390,9]
 unused fnc sequence [...js:33432,9]
 unused fnc keyframes [...js:33610,9]
 unused fnc asNativeElements [...js:34425,9]
 unused fnc getAllDebugNodes [...js:34458,9]
Side effects in init of unused var NgModuleRef [...js:35371,4]
 unused fnc clearModulesForTest [...js:35503,9]
 unused fnc getModuleFactory [...js:35512,9]
Side effects in init of unused var NgModuleFactoryLoader [...js:35486,4]
Side effects in init of unused var EmbeddedViewRef [...js:35866,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ReflectionInfo [...js:36465,4]
 unused fnc scheduleMicroTask [...js:36907,9]
 unused fnc getTypeNameForDebugging [...js:36914,9]
 unused fnc isBlank [...js:36931,9]
 unused fnc isBoolean [...js:36934,9]
 unused fnc isNumber [...js:36937,9]
 unused fnc isString [...js:36940,9]
 unused fnc isfnc [...js:36943,9]
 unused fnc isType [...js:36946,9]
 unused fnc isStringMap [...js:36949,9]
 unused fnc isStrictStringMap [...js:36953,9]
 unused fnc isPromise [...js:36956,9]
 unused fnc isArray [...js:36961,9]
 unused fnc isDate [...js:36964,9]
 unused fnc noop [...js:36967,9]
 unused fnc stringify [...js:36968,9]
 unused fnc serializeEnum [...js:36987,9]
 unused fnc deserializeEnum [...js:36990,9]
 unused fnc resolveEnumToken [...js:36993,9]
 unused fnc looseIdentical [...js:37123,9]
 unused fnc getMapKey [...js:37128,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBlank [...js:37131,9]
 unused fnc normalizeBool [...js:37134,9]
 unused fnc isJsObject [...js:37137,9]
 unused fnc print [...js:37140,9]
 unused fnc warn [...js:37143,9]
 unused fnc setValueOnPath [...js:37176,9]
 unused fnc getSymbolIterator [...js:37194,9]
 unused fnc evalExpression [...js:37213,9]
 unused fnc isPrimitive [...js:37223,9]
 unused fnc hasConstructor [...js:37226,9]
 unused fnc escape [...js:37229,9]
 unused fnc escapeRegExp [...js:37232,9]
Side effects in init of unused var Math [...js:36920,4]
Side effects in init of unused var STRING_MAP_PROTO [...js:36952,4]
Side effects in init of unused var StringWrapper [...js:36996,4]
Side effects in init of unused var StringJoiner [...js:37064,4]
Side effects in init of unused var NumberWrapper [...js:37073,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RegExp [...js:37114,4]
Side effects in init of unused var fncWrapper [...js:37115,4]
Side effects in init of unused var Json [...js:37147,4]
Side effects in init of unused var DateWrapper [...js:37157,4]
 unused var _symbolIterator [...js:37193,4]
Side effects in init of unused var platformBrowser [...js:37430,4]
Side effects in init of unused var RenderDebugInfo [...js:38410,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ReflectionCapabilities [...js:38411,4]
Side effects in init of unused var VIEW_ENCAPSULATION_VALUES [...js:38412,4]
Side effects in init of unused var reflector [...js:38414,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AnimationPlayer [...js:38416,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AnimationSequencePlayer [...js:38417,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AnimationGroupPlayer [...js:38418,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AnimationKeyframe [...js:38419,4]
Side effects in init of unused var AnimationStyles [...js:38420,4]
Side effects in init of unused var prepareFinalAnimationStyles [...js:38421,4]
Side effects in init of unused var balanceAnimationKeyframes [...js:38422,4]
Side effects in init of unused var clearStyles [...js:38423,4]
Side effects in init of unused var collectAndResolveStyles [...js:38424,4]
 unreachable code [...js:38818,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:38818,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__common_audio_proxy___default [...js:38621,25]
 unreachable code [...js:38975,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:38975,4]
 unreachable code [...js:39042,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:39042,4]
 unreachable code [...js:39110,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:39110,4]
 unreachable code [...js:39172,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:39172,4]
 unreachable code [...js:39228,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:39228,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__polyfills_ts___default [...js:40907,25]
 unused fnc unimplemented [...js:41724,9]
Side effects in init of unused var WrappedError [...js:41761,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__location_location_strategy__ [...js:41785,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__location_hash_location_strategy__ [...js:41786,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__location_path_location_strategy__ [...js:41787,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__location_location__ [...js:41788,25]
Side effects in init of unused var HashLocationStrategy [...js:41862,4]
Side effects in init of unused var PathLocationStrategy [...js:41969,4]
 unused var __unused [...js:42060,4]
 unused fnc _fetchSylesFromState [...js:43009,9]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_21__template_parser_template_ast__ [...js:43449,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_22__compile_metadata__ [...js:43450,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_23__offline_compiler__ [...js:43451,25]
 unused var NaN [...js:43667,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ml_parser_interpolation_config__ [...js:43957,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__schema_element_schema_registry__ [...js:43958,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__i18n_index__ [...js:43959,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__template_parser_template_ast__ [...js:43960,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__private_export__ [...js:43961,25]
Side effects in init of unused var OfflineCompiler [...js:44924,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __compiler_private__ [...js:45770,4]
 unused var renderMethod [...js:46855,12]
Side effects in init of unused var _animationViewCheckedFlagMap [...js:46806,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__util__ [...js:47600,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__application_init__ [...js:47604,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__profile_profile__ [...js:47614,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_21__animation_animation_transition_event__ [...js:47620,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_22__animation_animation_player__ [...js:47621,25]
 unused var __unused [...js:48086,4]
 unused var NaN [...js:48902,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__linker_ng_module_factory_loader__ [...js:48915,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__linker_system_js_ng_module_factory_loader__ [...js:48917,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__linker_view_ref__ [...js:48920,25]
Side effects in init of unused var SystemJsNgModuleLoader [...js:49162,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ContentChildren [...js:49758,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ContentChild [...js:49791,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ViewChildren [...js:49828,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__util_decorators__ [...js:50122,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__directives_ng_control__ [...js:50281,25]
 unused var FORM_DIRECTIVES [...js:50375,4]
 unused var REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES [...js:50379,4]
Side effects in init of unused var ReactiveFormsModule [...js:50471,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__directives_abstract_control_directive__ [...js:50492,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__directives_abstract_form_group_directive__ [...js:50493,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__directives_checkbox_value_accessor__ [...js:50494,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__directives_control_container__ [...js:50495,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__directives_control_value_accessor__ [...js:50496,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__directives_default_value_accessor__ [...js:50497,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__directives_ng_control__ [...js:50498,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__directives_ng_control_status__ [...js:50499,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__directives_ng_form__ [...js:50500,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__directives_ng_model__ [...js:50501,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__directives_ng_model_group__ [...js:50502,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__directives_reactive_directives_form_control_directive__ [...js:50503,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__directives_reactive_directives_form_control_name__ [...js:50504,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__directives_reactive_directives_form_group_directive__ [...js:50505,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14__directives_reactive_directives_form_group_name__ [...js:50506,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15__directives_select_control_value_accessor__ [...js:50507,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16__directives_select_multiple_control_value_accessor__ [...js:50508,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_17__directives_validators__ [...js:50509,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_18__form_builder__ [...js:50510,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_19__model__ [...js:50511,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_20__validators__ [...js:50512,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__private_export__ [...js:50623,25]
Side effects in init of unused var RESOURCE_CACHE_PROVIDER [...js:50642,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __platform_browser_dynamic_private__ [...js:50659,4]
Side effects in init of unused var getDOM [...js:50682,4]
 unused fnc enableDebugTools [...js:50967,9]
 unused fnc disableDebugTools [...js:50976,9]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__common_tools__ [...js:50941,25]
Side effects in init of unused var context [...js:50953,4]
Side effects in init of unused var By [...js:51003,4]
Side effects in init of unused var document [...js:51391,4]
Side effects in init of unused var location [...js:51392,4]
Side effects in init of unused var gc [...js:51393,4]
Side effects in init of unused var performance [...js:51394,4]
Side effects in init of unused var Event [...js:51395,4]
Side effects in init of unused var MouseEvent [...js:51396,4]
Side effects in init of unused var KeyboardEvent [...js:51397,4]
Side effects in init of unused var EventTarget [...js:51398,4]
Side effects in init of unused var History [...js:51399,4]
Side effects in init of unused var Location [...js:51400,4]
Side effects in init of unused var EventListener [...js:51401,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__browser_title__ [...js:51410,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__browser_tools_tools__ [...js:51411,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__dom_animation_driver__ [...js:51412,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__dom_debug_by__ [...js:51413,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__dom_debug_ng_probe__ [...js:51414,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__dom_dom_tokens__ [...js:51415,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__dom_events_event_manager__ [...js:51416,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__dom_events_hammer_gestures__ [...js:51417,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__security_dom_sanitization_service__ [...js:51418,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__app_component__ [...js:52125,25]
 unreachable code [...js:52191,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:52191,4]
 unreachable code [...js:52504,4]
Declarations in unreachable code! [...js:52504,4]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_core_js_es6_symbol___default [...js:52571,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_core_js_es6_object___default [...js:52573,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_core_js_es6_fnc___default [...js:52575,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_core_js_es6_parse_int___default [...js:52577,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_core_js_es6_parse_float___default [...js:52579,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_core_js_es6_number___default [...js:52581,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6_core_js_es6_math___default [...js:52583,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7_core_js_es6_string___default [...js:52585,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8_core_js_es6_date___default [...js:52587,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9_core_js_es6_array___default [...js:52589,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_core_js_es6_regexp___default [...js:52591,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11_core_js_es6_map___default [...js:52593,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12_core_js_es6_set___default [...js:52595,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13_core_js_es6_reflect___default [...js:52597,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_14_core_js_es7_reflect___default [...js:52599,25]
Side effects in init of unused var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_15_zone_js_dist_zone___default [...js:52601,25]
Condition always true [...js:56098,5]
Non-strict equality against boolean: == false [...js:57483,25]
Condition left of || always false [...js:56627,38]
Condition left of || always false [...js:56630,38]
Side effects in init of unused var Zone$1 [...js:56112,4]

WARNING in styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Condition always false [styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js:15,3]
 unreachable code [styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js:17,1]
Side effects in init of unused var update [styles.0e8dc7102065bbe2b293.bundle.js:12,4]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset    Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  4.3 kB       0
    chunk    {0} index.html 1.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

Answer (score 2):

For explaination : the backend server launched by `ng serve` publishes your `src` folder, but all the `src` files won't be in your `dist` folder after build, only the needed ones.

You have to publish your image in an asset folder.

In your `src/angular-cli.json` file, check you have something like :

```
{
  "project": {
    ...
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
...
```

And then put your images in your `src/assets` folder. You could reference it by this way :

```
<img src="assets/mic_photo.png"/>
```

Go further by reading this discussion : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2126

Comment: Tried this. Now when i build the app i get "Assets" folder inside the dist folder. On the root of the dist folder i still get my background picture "uglyfied" but not the rest of the images?

Comment: for some reason i could not edit my post: 

Before, all my images were in ..../images folder, but in build only my background was uglyfied and moved to the root of the dist, rest of the images had to be included manualy.

Same thing now, all images are in "Assets" but only the background image gets uglyfied and moved to root. All the rest are in the newly created "Assets" folder in the root of dist.

Comment: I don't understand the new problem, maybe you could add a schema and your sources...

Comment: At first, all my images were in "images" folder inside the "app" folder. When i build the app, only my background picture was uglyfied by angular-cli: renamed to "asdf43kmk":ish and moved to the root of the "dist" during build.

Comment: all other images was "skipped" so on the builded app there was only 1 image. 

Now when i changed the app so that all images are in the assets, the background picture is still renamed to "adsdfsdf453" and moved to the root of the "dist", and all of the another images are left in the assets folder, and they keep the original file names.